# Magento 2 : Lifetime, scope and general usage for all types of sessions

Tags: magento2, session, customer-session, checkoutsession

There are a lot of session types in magento 2 . The ones I know of are listed below ;

```
1)  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Session.php

2) \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Session.php

3) \Magento\Persistent\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-persistent/Model/Session.php

4) \Magento\Customer\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Session.php

5) \Magento\Backend\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Session.php

6) \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session //vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php
```

Can someone please tell me about lifetime, scope and general usage for these sessions, so I can know which session to use when?

Answer (score 2):

> **Magento 2 provides five types of sessions:**

**Magento\Backend\Model\Session** - This session is used for the Magento backend.

**Magento\Catalog\Model\Session** - Catalog session is used for the frontend for product filters.

**Magento\Checkout\Model\Session** - Checkout session is used to store checkout-related information.

**Magento\Customer\Model\Session** - Customer session is used for customer, frontend login, and all other activities.

**Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session** -  For newsletter data.

**Magento\Persistent\Model\Session** - Persistent session data is kept in DB - so it’s not deleted in some days and is kept for as much time as we need. DB session keeps customerId + some data from real customer session that we want to sync (e.g. num items in shopping cart).